# Qt5 Linux - intercept maximize and span application across two screens?

Tags: qt, xcb

I have a strange requirement to have a Qt application maximize itself across two screens of a dual-monitor setup. I understand I will need to do some special magic to make this happen, since it is not the standard behaviour.

I have a QAbstractNativeEventFilter specialized, and inside of its nativeEventFilter() function I am grabbing the xcb_generic_event_t that comes in. I have little experience with xcb, so I am not sure quite where to go from there.

I assume that if the response_type == XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY, then I will need to somehow get an atom back that matches _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ and work from there.

However I don't know exactly how to go about doing that either via Qt or Xcb. So far, I have:

```
bool my_nef::nativeEventFilter( const QByteArray& event_type, void* message, long* )
{
 xcb_atom_t* a = xcb_get_property_value
  if ( event_type.toStdString() == "xcb_generic_event_t" ) {
    xcb_generic_event_t* ev = static_cast<xcb_generic_event_t*>(message);
    if ( ev->response_type == XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY ) {
      xcb_property_notify_event_t* ne = (xcb_property_notify_event_t*)ev;
    }
  }  

  return false;
```

}

And I do get the XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY. I just don't know what to do with it to check for a horizontal maximization.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Why not creating two separate windows which maximize each on another screen? Place widgets accordingly and the result should be nearly the same. (Except desktop tray but you might take on this kind of easier).

Comment: Check `QDesktopWidget`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html

Comment: Some expectation management: You can do a lot of magic, but in the end the window manager is the one to decide what happens. Some window managers may not even allow this behavior at all. If you want full independence, you need to bypass the window manager.